# Can't get SFML for Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, sfml

**What I'm trying to do**
I'm trying to get the SFML binding for Python 2.7. 32-bit version of python using windows.

https://python-sfml.org/download.html

**What I've tried**

There exe doesn't work because when you click or save the link it returns nothing and says it's missing.
I also used PIP to install Cython which I have, though when I try to use PIP to download pysfml, pySFML, python-sfml or sfml-python, pip tells me:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement sfml(from versions:)
No matching distribution found for pysfml.
```

When I try pip install -vvv pysfml

It also tells me that there is no matching distribution for pysfml.

**What I'm asking for**

How do I download this library? How do I get it to work for python 2.7

Comment: I think they may be having issues with their website at the moment as I'm getting the same issues when trying to manually download the exe. In terms of pip I have searched PyPi to see if the SFML package exists and I can't see it which explains why you can't find the package via pip. 

I notice the github for pysfml is fairly active and they have instructions on manually compiling it if that interests you, find that [here](https://github.com/Sonkun/python-sfml)

Comment: @Dillanm It says to download a windows sdk. When i click the link to do that, i have to choose from 3 files. Which ones do I choose? Or do I choose all? It doesn't specify on the website but it says to download a certain one if you using amd64 python. I don't know if you know or not but should I just download all? It's 5gb..

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know about those; hopefully someone else can come in to help you. Hopefully the creators of the site fix the download links, I'm going to email in the hopes they sort it out.

Answer (score 1):

Have emailed the main developers of PySFML and they responded with this:

> Thanks for letting us know, we're very aware of this. I already rewrote each page (download + compilation) but download links come with the actual per-compiled packages which aren't created yet. I'll upload them as soon as I finish to setup the continuous integration service that will automate the delivery of these per-compiled packages.
>
> Expect one week before things are done.

Looks like it's just part of the site overhaul that's on-going and should be resolved soon.

Furthermore:

> There were never uploaded.^^ These bindings had never been ready for this until recently (see recent commits). However, you can pip install directly from the repository, it must be something like `pip git+https://github.com/Sonkun/python-sfml?egg=pySFML`.
>
> I know compiling these bindings isn't a straight forward task, however, feel free to ask for assistance. :)
>
> PS: you must use SFML 2.3.2