# Issue installing PySFML with pipenv

Tags: python, pip, pipenv

I tried following the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41810246/cant-get-sfml-for-python-2-7) to install PySFML. `pip` flat out would not accept this command:

```
pip git+https://github.com/Sonkun/python-sfml?egg=pySFML
ERROR: unknown command "git+https://github.com/Sonkun/python-sfml?egg=pySFML"
```

I tried with `pipenv` (which is what I ideally want to use anyway) and it gave:

```
pipenv install git+https://github.com/Sonkun/python-sfml?egg=pySFML
zsh: no matches found: git+https://github.com/Sonkun/python-sfml?egg=pySFML
```

I changed the url to be a `#` instead of a `?` and it seemed to start working but then:

```
Installing git+https://github.com/Sonkun/python-sfml#egg=pysfml…
⠦Warning: You installed a VCS dependency in non–editable mode. This will work fine, but sub-dependencies will not be resolved by $ pipenv lock.
  To enable this sub–dependency functionality, specify that this dependency is editable.
Collecting pysfml from git+https://github.com/Sonkun/python-sfml#egg=pysfml
  Cloning https://github.com/Sonkun/python-sfml to /tmp/pip-build-7z0jrlmi/pysfml

Error:  An error occurred while installing git+https://github.com/Sonkun/python-sfml#egg=pysfml!
No files/directories in /tmp/pip-build-7z0jrlmi/pysfml/pip-egg-info (from PKG-INFO)
```

(Note: switching `?` to `#` gives the same error for `pip`)

How can I proceed from here to get `pipenv` to install PySFML?

Answer (score 1):

Seems that it needs some tag.

In https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#installing-packages

> Requirements files are used to override a dependency with a local
>   patch that lives in version control. For example, suppose a
>   dependency, SomeDependency from PyPI has a bug, and you can't wait for
>   an upstream fix. You could clone/copy the src, make the fix, and place
>   it in VCS with the tag sometag. You'd reference it in your
>   requirements file with a line like so:
>
> `git+https://myvcs.com/some_dependency@sometag#egg=SomeDependency`
>
> If SomeDependency was previously a top-level requirement in your
>   requirements file, then replace that line with the new line. If
>   SomeDependency is a sub-dependency, then add the new line.